# Cloudflare page NextJS environment variables not being read

Tags: next.js, cloudflare-pages

I am hosting a NextJS site on cloudflare pages but I can't read the environment variables.

Locally I am using in `.env.local`:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL=https://localhost:5001/
```

And reading it in code:

```
const apiUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL;
```

It works fine locally but when I try to set `NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL` or `API_URL` in cloudflare pages environment variables the code always reads an empty string.

I am not using edge runtime, I am using static site with `next export`

What am I doing wrong?  How can I read the env var on cloudflare pages?

Comment: Any update on the issue?

Answer (score 0):

tldr: the values of all `NEXT_PUBLIC_` environment variables are locked at build time.

The NextJs docs for [Bundling Environment Variables for the Browser](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#bundling-environment-variables-for-the-browser) has a footnote that says:

"Note: After being built, your app will no longer respond to changes to these environment variables. For instance, if you use a Heroku pipeline to promote slugs built in one environment to another environment, or if you build and deploy a single Docker image to multiple environments, all NEXT_PUBLIC_ variables will be frozen with the value evaluated at build time, so these values need to be set appropriately when the project is built. If you need access to runtime environment values, you'll have to setup your own API to provide them to the client (either on demand or during initialization)."